# XAMPP for linux: how to get information about an error 500?

Tags: apache, xampp, logging

im gettin an error 500 in xampp. When i open /opt/lampp/logs/access_log i get this line:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2010:23:02:53 +0200] "GET /miembros HTTP/1.1" 500 1900
```

Is there any way to get more information (cause, etc) about the error ?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 1):

Yes

```
/opt/lampp/logs/error_log
```

or whatever is configured as your error_log in apache.

The access_log lists only files that were accessed by web clients.

The error_log instead lists the error messages that occured while generating the web pages.